# print the first item in list of lists

Tags: python, list

I am trying to print the first item in a list of lists.  This is what I have:

My list is like this:

```
['32 2 6 6', '31 31 31 6', '31 2 6 6']
```

My code is:

```
from operator import itemgetter

contents = []
first_item = list(map(itemgetter(0), contents))
print first_item
```

but itemgetter only returns:
['3', '3', '3'] istead of ['32', '31', '31']
can I use a delimiter?

Comment: You should do `str.split(" ")[0]` in order to get the first NUMBER in the string

Comment: It's not the first item (which would be the first character), but for the first number `[item.split()[0] for item in l]`

Comment: Relating to your previous question, this can all be done when reading the file, I think you are trying to go a very roundabout way to solve whatever problem you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are dealing with a list of strings, so you are getting the first index of each string, which is in fact `3` for all of them. What you should do is a comprehension where you split each string on space (which is the default of split) and get the first index:

```
first_element = [s.split(None, 1)[0] for s in contents]
```

Inside the comprehension, the result of each `s.split(None, 1)` will actually be =>

`['32', '2 6 6']` `['31', '31 31 6']` `['31', '2 6 6']`

and you get the first index of that.

Output:

```
['32', '31', '31']
```

Comment: I would `s.split(None, 1)` if you just want the first.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I never thought of that! thanks. I'll update that.

Comment: Also if you really want to go functional  without a lambda, `list(map(itemgetter(0), map(methodcaller("split", None, 1), contents)))` ;)

Comment: haha. That is a pretty intense functional way of doing it, but purely functional nonetheless. :)

Comment: I suppose `[s[0] for s in map(methodcaller("split", None, 1), contents)]` might be the best of both  worlds!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham hehe, the hybrid approach.

Comment: @idjaw I think the `Non-ideal solutions` should probably be a separate answer. The first answer was perfect, they non ideal solutions are non ideal and bring down the quality

Comment: @jamylak Appreciate the feedback! TBH I would rather do without those answers. The only reason why I had them was for the sake of the OP, because they were using them. Thinking it over, choosing only the *ideal* solution would have been just fine here. I'm just going to remove the solutions and leave the one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> items = ['32 2 6 6', '31 31 31 6', '31 2 6 6']
>>> [s.partition(' ')[0] for s in items]
['32', '31', '31']
```